# FeynCalc example — muon decay — integration issue

Tags: physics, feyncalc

I'm just starting out using Mathematica and I'm trying to work through one of the examples given for FeynCalc, specifically the muon decay: https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/blob/master/FeynCalc/Examples/EW/Tree/Mu-ElAnelNmu.m

It seems to be working fine up until line 117,

```
diffDecayRate = 
  prefac d3q1/En[q1] d3q2/En[q2] d3k/En[k] delta4[q - q1 - q2] ampSquared[1]
```

The output for this is

> ```
> (16 d3k d3q1 d3q2 Subscript[G, F]^2 delta4[q - Subscript[q, 1] - 
>     Subscript[q, 2]] tr[-(OverBar[k] "\[CenterDot]" OverBar[Subscript[q, 1]])] 
>       tr[-(OverBar[p] "\[CenterDot]" OverBar[Subscript[q, 2]])])) /
>   (En[k]*En[Subscript[q, 1]] En[Subscript[q, 2]])
> ```

that is:

[image]

which clearly isn't correct, and from there the integral cannot be evaluated. Has anyone else come across this, and is it immediately obvious what I might be doing wrong?

Please let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: The examples from the master branch work only with the development version. If you install the stable version, only the examples shipped with it are guaranteed to work.

Comment: Ah ok thank you!